# How to make a alert dialog button left and right instead of both align right without using custom view in android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Here is the general way I build an alert dialog. It is not crash just the outcome doesn't suit my expectation.

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_fire_missiles)
           .setPositiveButton(R.string.fire, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   // FIRE ZE MISSILES!
               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   // User cancelled the dialog
               }
           });
    // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
   builder.create().show();
```

Outcome:

[image: dialog1]

But what I want is the cancel and fire button use up all the space of the dialog box rather than both align at the right side.

[image]

Just like the cancel and ok button. Ignore the check box what I need is only those button position.

Since I saw a lot of other app such as vine,twitter,foursquare etc display the alert dialog with the button which I desire so is there a way or method I can assign to the alert dialog while create it, I know there is a lot of way which can achieve this but I'm wondering is there a way without to use custom view or edit the `LayoutParams` of the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So recently I been talking to one of twitter developer what he said is every device have difference way to manage their user interface. Even there is a way better to use a custom dialog to make sure that on all device it is presenting the way what you want it to look like.

Final outcome use a custom dialog if you really want it to look like which way you want to.